# How to retrieve tag elements from an external page DOM and and show just the headings/summaries

Tags: jquery, dom, import, load

I have a news page with user maintained news items (headings, summaries and details/images). 
I want to show just the top 3 news headings from this page on another page. I've done the following, but to no avail. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#newsdata").load('news.php h4');

      var node = document.queryselector('#newsdata');
      var h4node = node.getelementbyTagName("h4");

      var x = "<a href=\"news\">"+ h4node[0].textcontent + "<\/a>";
      var y = "<a href=\"news\">"+ h4node[1].textcontent + "<\/a>";
      var z = "<a href=\"news\">"+ h4node[2].textcontent + "<\/a>";
      var content = x + "<hr>" + y + "<hr>" + z ;

      document.querySelector('#newsdiv').appendChild(content);
      alert(content); 
});
```

Comment: And what errors are reported in your console?

Comment: ajax is asynchronous...you need to modify the new html inside the success callback of `load()`. See docs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code matches what is here, but shouldn't 
`getelementByTagName` be `getElementsByTagName`?